# Calculated Column based on Date

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I am looking to return a calculated value based on a column named Date, I have three options I need to consider: 
If Date is between today and next 6 days return **A**
If Date is more than 6 days ahead but in this month return **B**
If Date is this after the 10th day month and before the end of the following month return **B** else return **C**

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not achievable because you cannot specify a TODAY or ME value in a calculated column, You do however, have the option to build a workflow that can insert these dates into a "Today" column and then have your calculated column reference this one. However, depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may need to build a looping workflow that pauses 24 hours or whatever. It really just depends on what you are trying to achieve with this list etc.